# Which is correct: "feedback is welcome" or "feedback is welcomed"?

Tags: word-choice

I am used to writing *feedback is welcome*. Is that correct, or should I write *feedback is welcomed*? Why?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

They are both correct, but the sense is a little different. In the first one 'welcome' is being used as an adjective. The second one is a passive construction--'feedback is welcomed (by us)'. Even though they mean basically the same thing, I like the first one better. The active voice is simpler and sounds stronger.