# Which one is correct please?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I'm wondering about these two sentences, I want to know which one is correct please

- Foreigners are welcome to apply
- Foreigners are welcomed to apply

Comment: See [M-W: **welcome {adjective}** {3}](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/welcome): 'willingly [gladly] permitted or admitted'. Compare 'We were happy to oblige' / 'You are free to apply' (not 'freed to apply'). //// There _are_ a disturbingly large number of examples of 'welcomed to apply' on the internet.

Comment: In this context, *welcome* has the sense of permission while *welcomed* has that of hugs as an inducement to apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You are welcome" or "You are welcomed" or "You welcome"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/you-are-welcome-or-you-are-welcomed-or-you-welcome)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps posts saying "Foreigners are welcomed to apply" are placed by foreigners to English-speaking countries