# "More is welcome" or "More is welcomed"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, differences

Which one of the following expressions is grammatical?

1. Please donate $5. More is **welcome**!
2. Please donate $5. More is **welcomed**!

Comment: I think they are of about equal wrongness; perhaps the latter is grammatically better; but I would say "More is better" instead.

Comment: @jwpat7: Thanks for your suggestion. Is the 1st one somehow related to "You are welcome"? In other words, are they the same type of construction?

Comment: I suspect there's an element of formality in the choice between the two.

Comment: @jwpat7: I disagree. The first is better than the second, but in the context of such "deferential requests" you'd more likely phrase it *"More **would be** welcome!"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is correct: "feedback is welcome" or "feedback is welcomed"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/which-is-correct-feedback-is-welcome-or-feedback-is-welcomed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both grammatical:

- *[Welcome](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/welcome)* is an adjective which means *agreeable* or *gladly received*.
- *Welcome* is also a verb meaning *to receive or accept with pleasure*.  Formed into a past participle, which functions as an adjective, it is *welcomed*.

*More is welcome* is definitely the one you want, since it implies to the viewer that they are being targeted by the statement.  *More is welcomed*, on the other hand, sounds like a bare statement of fact that you currently accept more, without the same appeal to the individual viewer.

Answer (score 3):

- "More is welcomed" relates to the money being welcomed (greeted at the door), should it arrive.
- "More is welcome" relates to the concept of "more" being welcome (door is always open), should it arrive or not.

Also,

- the first implies that you intend to thank them when they give you money.
- the second is more in spirit with the sentence: "Thanks, door's open, just leave it on the table", thus not necessarily implying an immediate thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Welcome" is correct as it is the standard adjective.

"Welcomed" is a past participle, which are often similar to the adjective form, but in this case a different adjective exists, i.e. "welcome".