# "Welcome" or "Welcomed" in British English or American

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I thought about telling someone "You're most welcome, and accepted." Should I have said ***most welcomed*** instead of ***welcome***?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Why do you think it should be one and not the other?

Comment: I always say "welcome", but today someone told me that it's "welcomed". I tried searching it but all I found was "you are welcome" and nothing about the structure of the sentence I used.

Comment: @user351683 I'd be skeptical of "someone"'s usage advice in future...

Comment: Both "welcome" and "welcomed" are valid.  Traditionally, "welcome" is more common in the US, but "welcomed" carries more of a sense of a conscious act vs just a sort of "blessing".  ("You are welcome and accepted", however, is a bit weird.)

Comment: Are you using this as a greeting, perhaps welcoming someone to your home or an event, or are you using it as a response to "Thank you"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct: "feedback is welcome" or "feedback is welcomed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/which-is-correct-feedback-is-welcome-or-feedback-is-welcomed)

Answer (score 2):

In American English (and British English so far as I know) the idiom is "You're welcome"

> **you're welcome** *idiom*
>
> used as a response after being thanked by someone
>
> [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%27re%20welcome)

Saying "You're welcomed" sounds strange and only makes sense if you're describing the actual process of being welcomed to someone in the second person, for example in the sentence: "You are welcomed into the house by your host".

---

I should say, I've never heard anyone use the additional "and accepted" part of this phrase. In the US, at least, the phrase is just "You're [most/very] welcome".

Comment: Yes. And all of that is the same in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no - the way you said it was correct. In the phrase "you're welcome", *welcome* is an adjective (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/welcome). Saying "you're welcomed" would be as weird as saying "you're talled" or "you're beautifulled".

Comment: Not exactly, because 'welcomed', unlike 'tall' or 'beautiful', is a past participle. 'When you arrive at the hotel, you're welcomed by your tour guide. After you're welcomed, you are served complimentary drinks and can get to know your fellow travellers....' 'You're talled' can never be acceptable and so sounds much weirder.

Answer (score -3):

Language, especially the English language, can sound very strange. Further, because something is popular doesn't mean it's correct.

To say "you're welcome" is poor grammar. "You're" is the contracted form of "you are". "You" is the subject and "are" the verb.

Now, in the case of "welcome", the actual verb in "you're welcomed" is "to be welcomed" making "are welcomed" a present participle. "You are welcomed" is, indeed, correct.

One doesn't say "you're honour" or "you're love" or "you're stupid" ().

Comment: To say "You are welcomed into the house" is just poor grammar. The issue is the voice in which one speaks. One should speak and write in Active Voice. If you are welcoming me into your home, why not just say, "Our family welcomes you"? That's active...and simple, and prevents you from eating your grammar with your crumpets.

Comment: "Welcome" is an adjective, just like "stupid" (and your example with that word is also completely grammatically correct, albeit informal).