# Is there a word that describes a loud exhale from the mouth to indicate tiredness?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure if it's correct to call it puff/puffing.
The definition is not close to what I'm looking for.
It's when you inhale deeply and release the air loudly.
The top result I found online is 'exhaled loudly'.
Just wondering if anyone knows of other words that can be used.

Comment: 'Phew!' is an ejaculation always considered at least quite exclamatory, signalling relief or perhaps less often surprise. But the relief might be that an exam or hailstorm is over, not necessarily an _exhausting_ ordeal.

Comment: The sound you usually make when you're tired is a yawn.

Answer (score 10):

That's called a *sigh*.

> **Sigh:** Emit a long, deep audible breath expressing sadness, relief, tiredness, or similar.
>
> Harry sank into a chair and sighed with relief.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sigh)]

Comment: The word I was armed with for approaching this page!

Comment: The answer is correct. Note that a sigh is not necessarily due to tiredness; e.g. it can be a sigh of relief.

Comment: But sigh by itself is sadness, right? Otherwise it's, "sign of relief" or "sigh of exhaustion" and so on. In "Bob chopped 30 cords of wood then sighed", I want to know why he's still upset.

Comment: @OwenReynolds I wouldn’t agree. For me, all those are ‘sighs’ regardless of the intent.

Comment: Yes ... it works, it's an answer. But nowhere near specific enough (I'd agree that Owen is right about the default not being the tiredness-related usage.) Also, sighs don't need to be loud, so a poor answer.  And 'too obvious to be an answer' on a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree with you. However, there are loads of other atrocious questions not suitable for a site aimed at linguists. [Examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2121/365490) are [everywhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2116/365490). Would you be so kind to DV and CV them too? (I'd CV'd them a few days ago but no one else did so my votes got expired ??).

Comment: Voted to C first as no evidence of research. The second is a valid question; there are different protocols in different areas and institutions, but these should be explained and stated to be non-universal. // I'd run out of votes and lifetime if I went back finding all unsuitable questions. I make a stand where I come across unsuitable questions and/or answers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case of "this is too obvious to be the answer", but it sounds like you are describing "to yawn".

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

yawn
n 1: an involuntary intake of breath through a wide open mouth;
usually triggered by fatigue or boredom; "he could not
suppress a yawn"; "the yawning in the audience told him it
was time to stop"; "he apologized for his oscitancy" [syn:
{yawn}, {yawning}, {oscitance}, {oscitancy}]
v 1: utter a yawn, as from lack of oxygen or when one is tired;
"The child yawned during the long performance"

Comment: I don't disagree with this answer or the comment from @Barmar. But the OP is looking for the loud *exhale*. While the *yawn* has both in inhale and an exhale, the emphasis in your definition is (correctly) on the *inhale*, not the *exhale*.